# What is the Galitzianer minhag in regards to waiting between meat and milk?

Tags: minhag, kashrut-kosher, meat, dairy

My ancestors were Galitzianer Chassidim, and I'm trying to figure out the minhag of Galitziana in regards to waiting between eating meat and milk. Does anyone know what the minhag is?

Comment: If they were Chasidim, most likely they would have waited six hours between fleishig and milchig.

Comment: [Welcome to Mi Yodyea](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites/3887#3887), Yosi Tal-Or and thanks for bringing your question here. It would be a good idea to register your account, that way you can log in and answer questions, as well as receive notifications on the questions, answers, and comments you've left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Six hours. That's the default, what you'd see in "Poland", which included Galicia back then.

Three hours is German and British; one is Dutch; Sephardic practices vary widely.

(I also happen to know people with strong Galitzianer roots, and they keep six!)

Comment: Sources would greatly improve this. I know w Galicians who wait "into the fifth hour" which is different.

Comment: "Sephardic practices vary widely. But Ashkenazim default to six." That's backwards. You even just listed 3 options for Ashkenazim! If anything the default Ashkenzi position is 1 hour, and various stringencies above that were accepted in different places. It's Sefardim who default to 6.

Comment: My family comes from there, and can confirm that we keep six

Answer (score 3):

I am of Galitzian roots and we wait 6 hours. Ashkenazic Jews in general didn't used to wait six hours, based on the Rama it was accepted to wait 6 hours. Ashreinu!

Comment: Galitzianeryid, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for sharing!